# Intel quad port gigabit PCI-e card on Poweredge 410 

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, intel

I installed the card and booted the server. It showed the embeded two ports as `eth0` and `eth1`. From the PCI-e card it showed just 2 ports, one `eth2`, and another one as `eth0-renamed`.

I connected a cable to all the PCI-e card ethernet slots, only on two slots the backlit lights up, and on the other two it doesn't.

I booted into the BIOS and there also only two ports from the PCI-e card are shown.

So my question is: does ubuntu server kernel have divers for Intel quad port ethernet card? Or is it the card is a faulty one? And why are all 4 ports were not shown in the BIOS?

Comment: this is a server queston and I do not think it will do well on askubuntu personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the bios itself cannot see all the ports, the card may be incompatible with the motherboard or the card may be defective.

Comment: Sounds correct. If two ports don't even get link-level lights then it's a faulty card.